# Compare faster columns of different dataframes

Tags: r

Let's assume two dataframes: A and B containing data like the following one:

```
Dataframe: A              Dataframe: B
   ColA                     ColB1      ColB2
| Dog   |                 | Lion     | yes
| Lion  |                 | Cat      | 
| Zebra |                 | Elephant | 
| Bat   |                 | Dog      | yes
```

Want to compare the values of ColA to the values of ColB1, in order to insert yes in case of match in column ColB2. What I'm running is this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(A)){
         if (B[i,1] == A[j,1]){
             B[i,2] <- "yes"
         }  
    }   
}
```

In reality we re talking abaout 20000 lines. How could this become faster?

Comment: Please `dput` you example data.frames. The way that they are currently displayed is not helpful. If you want to try it yourself, take a look at `?match` and the `%in%` operator.

Comment: vectorization!! You basically need to check out `%in%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `%in%` operator to determine membership:

```
B$ColB2 <- B$ColB1 %in% A$ColA
```

`ColB2` will contain `TRUE/FALSE` dependent on whether value in `ColB1` of data frame `B` was found in `ColA` of data frame `A`.

For more info see:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. Apart from that, is it possible to avoid the nesting for Loop?